# Android: Cannot resolve symbol GoogleSignInOptions

Tags: android

Here is the code, that is in the `onCreate` function:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

This is my build.gradle (project level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ca.uoguelph.socs.cis3760.s2_g6"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I really don't know what is going. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class GoogleSignIn not found in auth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166386/class-googlesignin-not-found-in-auth-library)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out all I needed to do was import `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions`!

Comment: Yes, pressing Alt+Enter and selecting "import class" option from the drop down adds the import line implicitly

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your build.gradle (Module:APP) script with the CORRECT version of this library, according to your buildToolsVersion. So let's say your buildToolsVersion is 25.3.1, then you will need 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'

However, **one of the best way to get google authentication services/sign in working in a Android app**, is following this official documentation:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the latest `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth'` dependency in your project. `GoogleSignInOptions` is part of the `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin` package.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Just to log the problem. This happens when there is version conflict. Check the build message, and it will suggest the version you should be importing. The classpath version in main gradle (`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`) should be complaint with the version of jar included in the app gradle (`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'`)