# Class GoogleSignIn not found in auth library

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have got problem with signing to Google play by android app, i added:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
and
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
in my gradle dependencies. 
 I got only classes like: GoogleSignInApi or GoogleSignInAccount and i dont know how to import others.
 I mean classes like GoogleSignIn or GoogleSignInClient. I just dont see them in library.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Yea i found, you have to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`GoogleSignIn` / `GoogleSignInClient` were introduced in **Google Play services SDK version 11.6**.

Older versions have slightly different class names and require a GoogleApiClient.

Please upgrade to 11.6 from Android Studio and configure below dependency.

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [release note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) for version `11.6.0`

**In Auth Library :**

Added the [GoogleSignInClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient) and [GoogleSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn) classes. GoogleSignInClient provides the entry point for interacting with the Google Sign In API.

so inject `11.6.0` version of auth artifact.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

`compile` now deprecated so it's better to use `implementation`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Update PlayStore lib to latest version 46 from SDK manager->Extra
- Update all firebase dependencies to 1160

  ```
  //Firebase
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
  ```
- Update play-services-auth dependencies to 1160

  ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
  ```
- Update google-services dependency in project level build.gradle to 3.1.0. Note the maven google dependency:

> ```
> buildscript {
>      repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
>      }
>    }
>
>  allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         mavenCentral()
>         maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}
>
>      }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Only answer I found which show which versions of firebase to use with google sign in for version 11.6.0